# Unqualified name lookup applied instead of argument-dependent name lookup

Tags: c++, friend

Consider an example from the standard sec 3.4.1/3:

```
typedef int f;
namespace N 
{
    struct A 
    {
        friend void f(A &);
        operator int();
        void g(A a) 
        {
            int i = f(a);// f is the typedef, not the friend
                         // function: equivalent to int(a)
        }
    };
}
```

`f(a)` is postfix expression. How does compiler determine that `f(a)` is not a function call? I'm wondering when we have no error like `f previously declared of typedef int f`; as in the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int foo; //error: previous declaration of ‘typedef int foo’
class B
{
public:
    friend void foo(B b){ printf("3"); } //error: ‘void foo(B)’ redeclared as different kind of symbol

    static const int c=42;
};

int main(){ }
```

Comment: btw, a function call *is* a postfix-expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(In my version of the C++11 document the example is presented in 3.4.1/3).

The 3.4.1/3 clearly states that for the purposes of parsing, in order to perform the *initial* determination of whether this is a postfix expression or function call, a *usual* name lookup is performed. "Usual" means that the lookup is performed as described in the rest of 3.4.1 and *no ADL* is used at that initial stage. 3.4.1/3 explicitly says that "The rules in 3.4.2 have no effect on the syntactic interpretation of an expression." (3.4.2 is ADL).

In this example, while parsing `f(a)` the usual lookup is used to look for name `f`. It finds the global typedef-name `::f` and nothing else. This means that `f(a)` is treated as a postfix expression (a cast), not as a function call. Note, that friend declaration of function `f` inside `A` *refers* to function `N::f`, but it does not introduce a declaration of `N::f` into `N`. Since `N::f` function is not explicitly declared in `N` (it is not visible in `N`), the usual lookup does not see it. It only sees the global `::f`, which is a typedef-name.

If you want the usual name lookup to find the function in the first example, you have to declare that function in `N` explicitly

```
typedef int f;
namespace N 
{
    struct A;     // <- added
    void f(A &);  // <- added

    struct A 
    {
        friend void f(A &);
        ...
```

Now the declaration of `N::f` is visible in `N`. Now the usual name lookup will find `N::f` and treat that `f(a)` as a function call from the very beginning.

Your second example is seriously different from the first. You have no extra namespace there. Because of that the friend function declaration in `B` refers to the global `::foo` and claims that `foo` is a *function*. But the global `::foo` is already declared as a typedef-name. This contradiction is exactly what causes the error.

(Amusingly, C++03 version of the standard contained an example in 3.4.1/3, which was essentially equivalent to your second example. I.e. the example in the standard was ill-formed. This is reported as [Defect #139](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#139) of the standard.)

Comment: I don't understand from your answer the following: how does compiler determine that current expression is function call(isn't function call)?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv: As I said, when the compiler sees `f(a)` it performs the usual name lookup for name `f`. If it finds a function named `f`, then it assumes that `f(a)` is a function call. If it finds something else named `f`, then `f(a)` is not a function call. That's all.

Comment: Ok, but where can I find that in the spec? Can you get a reference to a corresponding clause?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv: The general rule is in 3.4.1/3. Then the rest of  3.4.1 describes the *usual* name lookup. And then 3.4.2 describes the ADL.