# What does usual name lookup mean?

Tags: c++

In sec. 3.4.1/3 said the following:

> For purposes of determining (during parsing) whether an expression is
>   a postfix-expression for a function call, the **usual name lookup rules**
>   apply

What does mean `usual name lookup` in that case? It is quite not obviously.

UPD: I'm looking for a quote from the stadard to define `usual name lookup` concept. It is because I have already non-formal definition from AndreyT in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820709/unqualified-name-lookup-applied-instead-of-argument-dependent-name-lookup/23820772#23820772) topic.

Answer (score 1):

@AndreyT answered you on your previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23820772/2805305

> "Usual" means that the lookup is performed as described in the rest of
>   3.4.1 and no ADL is used.

If you want to know what ADL is you can check these links:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup

Comment: Where is it specified in the standard?

Comment: I’m sorry cannot help you with the standard. You could edit your question in order to attract attention that you specifically need quotes from the standard.