# C++ name lookup - example from the standard

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I need an explanation on this example from standard [basic.lookup.unqual]/3:

```
typedef int f;
namespace N {
struct A {
    friend void f(A &);
    operator int();
    void g(A a) {
        int i = f(a); // f is the typedef, not the friend
                      // function: equivalent to int(a)
    }
};
}
```

I would argue that `void N::f(A &)` is closer than `int(a)` because it does not involve the type-cast operator. I cannot however be sure because the standard contains only one instance of "type cast".

---

By the way, compiling that code fails in MSVC2015 (but it works in clang and g++).

> Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'void' to 'int'

---

**UPDATE**
Addressing some of the comments.

1. Type casting is formally known as "type conversions" and they are covered in (12.3) (thanks jefffrey).
2. What I am looking for is a description of the syntax parsing. In particular, why `postfix-expression ( expression-list opt )` is trampled over by `simple-type-specifier ( expression-list opt )`. Since according to (5.2), both of those expression are evaluated left-to-right. Hence, out of the two candidates to be before the `(a)`, `::N::f` should be closer than `::f` when evaluating expressions in `::N::A::g`.

Comment: The next sentence explains it quite well: "the expression is not a function call".

Comment: _"I cannot however be sure because the standard contains only one instance of 'type cast'"_ Then search for the actual term it uses.

Comment: I don't accept the premise of your argument. It's actually just an assertion. Can you explain why you disagree with the standard example? What makes you think the other symbol is "closer" than the one that's actually used?

Comment: @Kerrek: That's logically untrue, though. You can't know that the expression is not a function call until after unqualified lookup is done, so this fact obviously cannot factor in to unqualified lookup.

Comment: FWIW §5.4 describes what you call "type cast".

Comment: @KerrekSB: there seems to be an order in which the syntax is parsed. But I do not think that is the list in [expr.post]. In that list, `postfix-expression ( expression-list opt )` is prior to `simple-type-specifier ( expression-list opt )`.

Comment: Related: [What does usual name lookup mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23822789/1639256)

Comment: It is unfortunately not entirely clear from the Standard how name lookup is supposed to work here. But this is merely a language-lawyer issue, it seems (implementations agree on this part). See [CWG 405](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue405)

Comment: @dyp: Reported as a [bug in MSVC2015](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1619106/name-lookup-is-not-standard) since it works appropriately in other compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.  As the note containing the example says (3.4/3):

> For purposes of determining (during parsing) whether an expression is a *postfix-expression* for a function call, the usual name lookup rules apply. The rules in 3.4.2 have no effect on the syntactic interpretation of an expression.

So first we need to know whether `f` is a *simple-type-specifier* or a *postfix-expression*, using name lookup rules that *don't* include section 3.4.2.  And under these rules, the function `N::f` is not visible.

7.3.1.2/3:

> If a `friend` declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace.  The `friend` declaration does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or qualified lookup (3.4.3).

Therefore the unqualified lookup does not see any declaration of `N::f` at all, and finds only `::f`, which is a typename.  So the syntax is *simple-type-specifier* `(` *expression-list* <sub>opt</sub> `)` and not *postfix-expression* `(` *expression-list* <sub>opt</sub> `)`, and argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2) does not apply.

( If the unqualified lookup had found a function name, 3.4.2 would apply and would be able to include `N::f` in the candidate list despite the lack of declaration.  If `N::f` had a previous declaration other than the `friend`  declaration, it would have won the unqualified lookup. )

Comment: This is exactly what I meant to write. Your answer is somewhat cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 2):

"Type casting" has nothing to do with this scenario. The rules for argument-dependent lookup include, from [basic.lookup.argdep]:

> Let X be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let Y be the lookup set produced by
>   argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If X contains
>   (3.1) — a declaration of a class member, or
>   (3.2) — a block-scope function declaration that is not a using-declaration, or
>   (3.3) — **a declaration that is neither a function or a function template**
>   then Y is empty. Otherwise Y is the set of declarations found in the namespaces associated with the argument types as described below. The set of declarations found by the lookup of the name is the union of
>   X and Y.

The lookup set produced by unqualified lookup for `f` is:

```
typedef int f;
```

That declaration is neither a function nor a function template, therefore Y is empty. We do not consider the friend function `f`, since it is not visible to unqualified lookup.

Comment: This very nicely explains how the "ADL opportunity" comes _after_ the initial bog-standard lookup. Surprisingly clear for the standard. Good find.

Comment: This is an interesting way to read it. [basic.lookup.argdep]p1 requires that `f` has already been identified as a *postfix-expression* for ADL to be applied. I don't quite see how we can arrive at that conclusion, though (related to CWG 405).

Comment: @dyp I think once we found a non-function for `f`, we just stop, and then no ADL happens. It may be suboptimally worded, but I don't know what else this section could mean.

Comment: I think that hinges on the possibility of a declaration set produced by unqualified lookup which contains [a function or function template] plus something else. I can't come up with such a set, but is such a set impossible?

Comment: @dyp I don't think it can contain more than one. A variable/function can hide a class name [basic.scope.hiding], but you can't have a variable and a function [basic.scope.declarative].

Answer (score 0):

The statements around the quote are actually quite clear on why the example does not call the function `f`:

> Because the expression is not a function call, the argument-dependent name lookup (3.4.2) does not apply and the friend function f is not found.

The actual question is *why* the argument-dependent look-up is not applies. It seems 5.2.3 [expr.type.conv] paragraph 1 applies:

> A *simple-type-specifier* (7.1.6.2) or *typename-specifier* (14.6) followed by a parenthesized *expression-list* constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list.

Clearly, `f` is a *simple-type-specifier*: the `typedef int f;` arranges for that to be the case. Remove this `typedef` and `f` isn't a *simple-type-specifier* anymore resulting in `N::A::f` being found.

Comment: That begs the question: Why is `f` a *simple-type-specifier* and not a *postfix-expression*? I guess this has to do with [basic.lookup.unqual]p3 requiring a *postfix-expression* to apply ADL, but I'm not sure if this isn't circular.

Comment: Well it needs to resolve `f`, agreed. But according to which rules? I'd look at [basic.lookup.unqual] and encounter p3 again. Either at this point, the expression has not yet been categorized, and hence, p3 does not apply; or, we run each possible interpretation through [basic.lookup.unqual] and see what happens. Which one is used doesn't seem to be specified, though it's fairly obvious the first one was meant.

Comment: On the other hand, if we remove `::f` and run through [basic.lookup.unqual], I don't think we find any declaration. Shouldn't this be illegal? (name used though not declared)

Comment: *"if other rules didn't find anything"* I agree (even though it can also add *additional* overloads). I just can't find the normative wording for this behaviour. The [basic.lookup.unqual] section has a lot of "a name used in ... shall be declared before ..." rules, and don't mention that ADL can make it legal to use that name nevertheless.

Comment: ... this is probably [CWG 405](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue405). The last part of the proposed resolution, that is.

Comment: @dyp: It seems to me that the proposed resolution became "The rules in 3.4.2 have no effect on the syntactic interpretation of an expression" in 3.4.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

According to [class.conv]/1 (emphasis mine):

> Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion **functions**.

Thus, both `::N::f` and `::N::A::operator int()` are functions. However, [namespace.memdef]/3 specifies (emphasis mine):

> If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template 97 the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. **The friend declaration does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup** (3.4.1) or qualified lookup (3.4.3).

Since `::N::f` is out of the picture while looking up for names, the closest is `::f` which then becomes `::N::A::operator int()`.

---

The following code should clarify things. Because it fails to compile (in clang), it shows that `::N::f` has preference over `::f` when `::N::f` is actually in the list of available names.

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef int f;
namespace N {
struct A;
void f( A & )
{
    std::cout << "::N::f\n";
}
struct A {
    friend void f(A &);
    operator int() { std::cout << "Yes, I am a function\n"; return 5; }
    void g(A a) {
        int i = f(a); // f is the typedef, not the friend
                      // function: equivalent to int(a)
        std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(f(a))>().pretty_name() << '\n';
        std::cout << i;
    }
};
}

int main()
{
    N::A a;
    a.g( a );
}
```

---

**Further explanation**

The part

```
void f( A & )
{
    std::cout << "::N::f\n";
}
```

is both the declaration (and the definition) of `::N::f`. That is, it introduces the name `::N::f` in the list of names contained in `::N`. When evaluating the `f` in `int i = f(a)`, we look in the list available names and we find `::N::f` before `::f`. Hence `f(a)` is type void and the code above fails to compile with the message "cannot initialize a type int with a type void". That is, `int i = f(a)` calls `::N::f` when `::N::f` is available even in the presence of `::N::A::operator int`.

On the other hand, if we remove the `::N::f` definition part, the name `::N::f` exists only as introduced by the friend declaration. Since such a name cannot be the result of a lookup, then the `f` in `f(a)` is the next available, which is the global typedef `::f`. Now that we know that the `f` in `f(a)` is int, we can call the function `::N::A::operator int`.

Comment: A conversion function is a function, but a conversion expression is not a function call expression. [expr.type.conv]

Comment: @Oktalist: The code in the update makes `::N::f` available for lookup. It then precedes `::f`.

Comment: Take the original code from the standard example and remove the `typedef int f;` and the `int i =`. It still compiles, as lookup finds the friend function, despite "the friend declaration does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup". http://ideone.com/oU0wue

Comment: @Oktalist: you want me to remove the part that needs explanation. I do not see how it helps.

Comment: It demonstrates that your quote from [namespace.memdef]/3 doesn't explain why lookup fails to find the friend function when the typedef is present. To understand the effect of the typedef, it is not unreasonable to observe the effect of removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard (n4296) says as 11.3 §1 (Member access control / Friends) *A class specifies its friends, if any, by way of friend declarations. Such declarations give
special access rights to the friends, but they do not make the nominated friends members of the befriending
class.*

And at 7.3.1.2 (Namespace member definitions) §3 *The friend declaration does not by
itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup or qualified lookup*
.

I slightly modified your example to make it simpler to see what actually happens:

1. any try to declare `f` outside `N` (meaning at top level scope) gives an error *redefinition of 'f' as different kind of symbol*, be it before of after the `namespace N` block

   ```
   typedef int f;

   namespace N {
   struct A {
       friend int f(A &);
       operator int();
       int g(A a) {
           int i = f(a); // f is the typedef, not the friend
                         // function: equivalent to int(a)
           return i;
       }
       int i;
       A(int i): i(i) {};
   };
   }


   int f(N::A& a) {  // Error here
       return 2*a.i;
   }
   N::A::operator int() {
       return this->i;
   }
   ```
2. if `f` is declared (in namespace `N`) **after** `int i = f(a)` `f` is taken as the int conversion:

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   typedef int f;

   namespace N {
   struct A {
       friend int f(A &);
       operator int();
       int g(A a) {
           int i = f(a); // f is the typedef, not the friend
                         // function: equivalent to int(a)
           return i;
       }
       int i;
       A(int i): i(i) {};
   };

   int f(A& a) {
       return 2*a.i;
   }
   }

   N::A::operator int() {
       return this->i;
   }

   int main() {
       N::A a(2);
       std::cout << a.g(a) << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   outputs 2
3. if `f` is declared **before** `int i = f(a)` the function declaration inside the namespace has precedence over int conversion:

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   typedef int f;

   namespace N {
   int f(struct A&); // <= simple DECLARATION here
   struct A {
       friend int f(A &);
       operator int();
       int g(A a) {
           int i = f(a); // f is the typedef, not the friend
                         // function: equivalent to int(a)
           return i;
       }
       int i;
       A(int i): i(i) {};
   };

   int f(A& a) {
       return 2*a.i;
   }
   }

   N::A::operator int() {
       return this->i;
   }

   int main() {
       N::A a(2);
       std::cout << a.g(a) << std::endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   outputs 4

TL/DR : The example on the standard assumes that there is no declaration of the function `f` before `int i = f(a);`. As a friend declaration in a class or in a namespace **does not** make the name visible to unqualified lookup or qualified lookup, the only declaration that is visible at that time is `typedef int f;`. So `f` is taken as the typedef.

But if there is a declaration for the function `f` in the namespace, it will take precedence over the typedef, because in N scope it hides the top level declaration.

Comment: Out-of-space definitions are OK. I think you are not using the correct name: `int ::N::f(::N::A &)`. Also, a friend declaration is, well, a declaration. The name is introduced in the namespace. See [dcl.spec] in the standard. However, it is not available for unqualified (or qualified lookup). See the section "further explanation" in my answer.

Comment: @Hector : `int ::N::f(::N::A &)` introduce name f in namespace N. My case 1 is just to say that you cannot redefine f at same scope level as the typedef. I've edited my post according to your other remark.

Comment: I understand your point now. I would insist however in an issue: the friend declaration is a declaration and it does introduce the name in the enclosing namespace. For example in point 2, you wrote "if `f` is declared … after `int i = f(a)`". Well, `::N::f` was declared before  `int i = f(a)` in your point 2 right in the `friend` declaration. You can check it say by trying a competing declaration that would cause problems at compilation: put `friend int f(A &);` right after the other `friend` declaration. The error message reaffirms that `::N::f` was indeed declared before `operator int()`.

Comment: The code for my last comment is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d027aa2ed3fbefa). The relevant message is "ambiguating new declaration of `int N::f(N::A&)`"